# read the content of text file nad display on standard output throgh batch file

Tags: batch-file

i have created one file file1.txt, content of file1.txt is "abcde".
I want to read  the content of file1.txt and print on standard output through batch file.
How to read the content of file and print on standard output via batch file.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
type file1.txt
```